# Why is CSS div element dropdown not displaying over another Grid Layout Row?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a Grid Layout that has three rows: a Header, Content and Footer.  Within my Header row I created a dropdown login box to replace my current login form.  The problem is the box gets cut off or does not display over the Grid Layout Content row.  It only displays within the Header row, so I only see a part of it as the dropdown login is to large to only fit within the Header row.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Nunito,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    background-color: #3399FF;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #858796;
}
/*-- Main grid view --*/
.main-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas: "header header" "content content" "footer footer";
}

.header {
    grid-area: header;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    background-image: url(../img/image1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.content {
    grid-area: content;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    background-image: url(../img/image2.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 5% 5%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.login-dropdown {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login-dropdown-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 100px;
    top: 52px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    padding: 1px;
}

.dropdown-arrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid #fff;
    right: 29px;
    top: 42px;
}
.footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 30% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
    "login-footer-grid login-footer-grid login-footer-grid"
}
.login-footer-grid {
    grid-area: login-footer-grid;
    align-self: center;
    max-height: calc(100vh + 10px);
    left: 1%;
    right: 1%;
    font-family: Nunito,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol","Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    bottom: 0;
}
.login-topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 0 1px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(50,53,57,0.2); /*rgb(199,221,113,1); */
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 28px 20px 28px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.login-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 50px 20px 30px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(15,15,15,0.6);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.login-form h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
}
.float-right {
    float: right;
}

.float-left {
    float: left;
}

/* Hover styles */
li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF7104;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/test.css">
    </head>
<body>
<!-- Main grid layout -->
<div class="main-grid">
        <!-- First grid row -->
        <div class="header">
            <!-- Logo containing navbar-->
            <ul class="login-topnav">
                <!-- New Dropdown user login element on navbar -->
                <li class="login-dropdown">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Login</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-arrow"></div>
                    <div class="login-dropdown-content">
                    <form>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Username.." name="unam" id="unam" required>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Password.." name="pwd" id="pwd" required>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Second grid row -->
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Login form to replace -->
            <div  class="login-form animate" >
                <form action= "" method="post">
                </form>
                <form action= "" method="post">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Third grid Row -->
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried setting a `z-index` for the `.login-dropdown-content`, but it did not help.
Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how to solve this?

Comment: I can't replicate this issue with the code provided - it all seems to be working as you intend: [codepen](https://codepen.io/lazaruswist/pen/rNVPwrE?editors=1100)

Comment: @Lawrence Witt I added the complete minimal example.  You now see the problem clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `overflow: hidden` in `.login-topnav` which hid the overflowed dropdown.

Removing the `overflow` property and giving it a fixed `height` should help:

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9c3hxgm/

Comment: It is a bit of a re-think.  But it works.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you maybe know why a jquery Datatable will cause the same problem with a modal view over the data section (tbody & thead)?

Comment: Nevermind I solved my own question.  Set the `z-index: 1` of the modal that should appear over a jquery dataTable.